# Concrete Mathmatics: Notation for sums of sums where inner sum depends on outer sum (equation 2.30)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation

### Summary

In Concrete Mathematics (Graham, Knuth, Patashnik) equation 2.30 is as follows

$$
\sum_{j \in J} \sum_{k \in K(j)} a_{j,k} = \sum_{k \in K'} \sum_{j \in J'(k)}a_{j,k}
$$

Does the $K'$ mean then the complement of some set $K$? The book says further down

> ..., because we can let $J = K'$ be the set of all integers ...

If $K'$ is the set of *all* integers (along with $J$ if I understand correctly) then what is it the complement of? The non-integers?

Comment: I don't have the book, but most likely $K'$ is either $\bigcup_{j\in J}K(j)$ or a superset of it (i.e. the set of all $k$'s that can ever appear in one of $K(j)$'s, or a bigger set) - and then $J'(k)$ is the set of all $j\in J$ such that $k\in K(j)$. That way, the sums are equal because all we did was to re-arrange the terms in the first sum to obtain the second sum. No complements are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the sentence that immediately follows (2.30):

> Here the sets $J,K(J),K'$, and $J'(k)$ must be related in such a way that $$[j\in J]\big[k\in K(j)\big]=[k\in K]\big[j\in J'(k)\big]\,.$$

In other words, we can reverse the order of summation by rewriting

$$\sum_{j\in J}\sum_{k\in K(j)}a_{j,k}$$

as

$$\sum_{k\in K'}\sum_{j\in J'(k)}a_{j,k}$$

whenever we can find $K'$ and $J'(k)$ for each $k\in K'$ such that

$$[j\in J]\big[k\in K(j)\big]=[k\in K]\big[j\in J'(k)\big]\,.$$

The sets $K'$ and $J'(k)$ for $k\in K'$ are not defined in (2.30): (2.30) simply describes in very general terms a kind of rearrangement of a double summation — reversing the order of summation — that is often very helpful, just as reversing the order of integration in a double iterated integral is often very helpful.

The authors then go on to illustrate a simple and rather common case,

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^na_{j,k}=\sum_{1\le j\le k\le n}a_{j,k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ka_{j,k}\,,$$

analogous to

$$\int_0^1\int_x^1f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=\int_0^1\int_0^xf(x,y)\,dx\,dy\,.$$

Comment: Thanks as always - I am still developing my mathematical fluency and sometimes take things a bit literally missing the more general point.

Comment: @FredClausen: You’re welcome.